# Consistent repeat search

Tags: search

Is there a way to do a forward (resp. backward) repeat search with `n` (resp. `N`) indifferently I start the research with `/`/`*` or `?`/`#`  ?

Comment: Are you saying you want `/` and `?` to behave identically and `*` and `#` to behave identically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where I copied these from, but they make `n` and `N` always go in the same direction

```
nnoremap <expr> n 'Nn'[v:searchforward] . 'zv'
nnoremap <expr> N 'nN'[v:searchforward] . 'zv'
```